# How do i access json response object fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, response

I am trying constructing a table after my response and attemtpting to append response data to the table. My response comes back correctly as shown below

```
Object {__type: "DomainLayer.BusinessLogic.UserOnlineCommunity", CommunityID: "15bb29d4-b451-4034-be7e-8197723e0a89", Description: "name", Detail: "yes", Link: "test"}
```

but i am trying to access the the fields such as Description, or Details, but when i debug and log those fields into the console as i am doing in the code below, i get undefined. how do i get the value of each field.

```
function UpdateOnlineCommunity(communityId, communityName, communityDescription, communityLink) {
var serviceData = JSON.stringify({
    'communityId': communityId,
    'communityName': communityName,
    'communityDescription': communityDescription,
    'communityLink': communityLink
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PresentationService.asmx/UpdateUserCommunity",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: serviceData,
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response.d;
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function () {
            var tblCommunity = $('#tblCommunity');
            console.log(this['Description']);
            var rowDescription = $('</tr></tr>');
            rowDescription.append('<td>' + this['Description'] + '</td>');

            var rowDetail = $('</tr></tr>');
            rowDetail.append('<td>' + this['Detail'] + '</td>');

            var rowLink = $('</tr></tr>');
            rowLink.append('<td>' + this['Link'] + '</td>');

            var rowUpdateBtn = $('</tr></tr>');
            rowUpdateBtn.append('<button>Update</button>');

            tblCommunity.append(rowDescription);
            tblCommunity.append(rowDetail);
            tblCommunity.append(rowLink);
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Assuming the data shown is the full response, you have a single object, `$.each` would loop over the properties of that object which you don't need to do. Just access them directly.  Also using 2 closing tags to create a `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is a single object, so the use of `each` is causing problems. You can simply access the properties of the object by using `data.Description` for example. Try this:

```
success: function (response) {
    var data = response.d;
    var tblCommunity = $('#tblCommunity');
    var rowDescription = $('<tr />').append('<td>' + data.Description + '</td>');
    var rowDetail = $('<tr />').append('<td>' + data.Detail + '</td>');
    var rowLink = $('<tr />').append('<td>' + data.Link + '</td>');
    var rowUpdateBtn = $('<tr />').append('<button>Update</button>');
    tblCommunity.append(rowDescription, rowDetail, rowLink);
},
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jophpjwu/)

Also note that the syntax you were using to create your elements - `</tr></tr>` was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, i did think the each will be the cause of the problem. but just did not think i can access it directly from the data that way.. thanks again